# facilitating long-duration time lapse application

Tags: post-processing, timelapse

I am doing a time lapse that requires about 36 hours, however my equipment limits me to a rather short-duration interval. The longest time lapse setting available is one photo every 60 seconds. The math works out to be 2160 photos -- which seems daunting since the format is RAW. I'm praying my 64GB SD card can handle the onslaught.

What I typically do for timelapse photos is:

```
1. open Adobe Premiere Pro
2. navigate to import media
3. check image sequence box
4. boom, done
```

However, right now, I'm afraid to use this method for this particular project; I'm concerned about crashes or ungodly rendering times. It would be nice if I could chop things down to one picture every 15 minutes, but I'm not sure how to do that manually.

### Question

Is there anything I can do to ease the strain on system resources beforehand? Or can anyone with experience on high-count image time lapses share their preferred solutions?

Comment: At 24fps, 2160 frame is only 90 seconds of footage.

Answer (score 3):

Search eBay/Amazon etc for "Intervalometer" - prices around $£€ 10 - cheap as chips.

They come with adaptors to fit just about any camera that can use one. Usually claim time-lapse intervals programmable up to 99 hours. They're all pretty generic Chinese devices, unbranded or branded with any number of different names.

Bonus: even without batteries they work as a regular remote shutter release.